# Nutch Installation

Tags: nutch

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>searcher.dir</name>
    <value>your_crawl_folder_here</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
For example, if your nutch directory resides at C:\nutch-0.9.0 and you specified crawl as the directory after the -dir command, then enter C:\nutch-0.9.0\crawl\ instead of your_crawl_folder_here.
```

I don't understand this part of the nutch install guide. Anyone working with nutch can explain for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the nutch web app can find the index and segments that were generated. Nutch looks for these in the index and segments subdirectories of the directory defined in the `searcher.dir` property.

Set `searcher.dir` to be the crawl directory containing the index and segments.

Answer (score 0):

In `<name>`, you are giving your crawler a name (e.g. My Nutch Spider) and in `<value>`, you are assigning a value to the name (e.g. any folder name where this name resides or is referring to `trunk/build/plugins`)